# codeigniter - redirect page

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

codeigniter recently is real pain even though it is easy to understand and handle. however, sometimes it is horrible. I was trying to redirect a page using Tank_auth and whenever the redirect happen, a `?` shows up in the url. on my localhost everything is ok, but on my web server this weird `?` comes out from nowhere.

any idea how to get rid of this **?** question mark??

Thanks

**Update #1**

I thought maybe someone is going to ask about the **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php? [NC,L]
```

**Update #2**

This is the redirect code:

```
function room()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/hit/two/');
    } else { bla blah
```

Comment: Can you post the "redirect" code as well?

Comment: yes, sure. I will add it to the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php? [NC,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I had to edit the config file at the codeigniter where you can activate or deactivate query string feature. I made False and the redirect worked 100% without **?** symbol. I hope someone find this useful. thanks